# Problem with searching twice due to nuxt3 pages folder structure

Tags: frontend, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

While migrating from vue3 to nuxt3, I am experiencing a problem with routing occurring twice in a row. I need help. I would really appreciate your help.

1. When entering through the /apt path, it routes to /apt/city.
   [image]
2. When entering the /apt/city route, if route.params.city is null, it assigns city as default and routes it.
   [image]
3. /apt/city/[city].vue just moves to the ApartmentName page
   [image]
4. If you change city to another value inside [apartmentName].vue and do router.push, it is called twice because of the nuxt3 folder structure. How do I modify it to only call it once?
   I have no idea how to handle it.

The function below is being executed twice.

```
const getAptSalesList = async (page) => {
  var response = null;
  try {
    response = await API.getAptSalesInfo(payload);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data", error);
  } 
  if (response != null) {
    let path = "/apt/city";
    if (city.value) {
      path += `/${city.value}`;
    }
    router.push({
      path: path,
    });
  } else {
    console.error("GET APT Sales Fail");
  }
};
```

The getAptSalesList function is being called in onMounted.

```
onMounted(() => {
  aptSalesList.value = [];
  getAptSalesList(1);
});
```

When the url changes from http://localhost:3000/apt/city/seoul to http://localhost:3000/apt/city/pusan, the function posted in the question (getAptSalesList) must be called only once. Now it is called twice.